# Outlook API - 401 unauthorized

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

Using the github repo located at https://github.com/jasonjoh/outlook-fetch and have so far been unable to get a successful response from the outlook API.

I can grab a token, but the API doesn't seem to want it.

I've double checked both the manifest and the permissions in AD in the management portal and all seems to be OK.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the client credential flow can be tricky, especially if it's you're first time. The certificate could be insufficient, or you could have missed a single step somewhere along the way.

There's also the matter of scope to consider. Given the steps I listed in the README, your app should be able to access any user **inside the organization where you registered the app**. If you're trying to access another organization's users, it will fail with 401. You would need to have an admin register the app inside that organization, then use the app ID from that registration.